# how to fix this please tell

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

hello I am new to js made a discord bot and now was making and mc server info command but getting this error
const json = await response.json();
^

RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values must be non-empty strings.
at Function.verifyString (/home/runner/js-try3/node_modules/discord.js/src/util/Util.js:416:41)
at Function.normalizeField (/home/runner/js-try3/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:544:19)
at /home/runner/js-try3/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:565:14
at Array.map ()
at Function.normalizeFields (/home/runner/js-try3/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:564:8)
at MessageEmbed.addFields (/home/runner/js-try3/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:328:42)
at MessageEmbed.addField (/home/runner/js-try3/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:319:17)
at Object.module.exports.run (/home/runner/js-try3/commands/minecraft/mcserverinfo.js:21:6) {
[Symbol(code)]: 'EMBED_FIELD_VALUE'

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

module.exports.run = async (Client, message, args, prefix) => {
  const Ip = args[0];
  if(!Ip) return
  message.reply('Please provide an Ip of a Minecraft java edition server');

  const response = fetch(`https://api.mcsrvstat.us/2/${Ip}`);
  const json = await response.json();

  if (!json.online) return
  message.reply('Hmm that dint work I guess you entered wrong ip or the server is offline');

  const info = new MessageEmbed()
  .setColor('RANDOM')
  .setTitle((json.hostname || Ip) + "Information")
  .setThumbnail(`https://eu.mc-api.net/v3/server/favicon/${Ip.toLowerCase()}`)
  .addField("Ip:", json.ip || "Unknown", false)
  .addField("Status:", json.online ?
           "Online": "Offline", false)
  .addField("port:", json.port || "Default", false)
  .addField('Version:', json.version || "Unknown", false)
  .addField("Players online:", json.players ? json.players.online : "Unknown", false)
  .addField("Max players allowed tto join at once:", json.players ? json.player.max: "Unknown", false)

  if(json.motd && json.motd.clean && json.motd.clean.length > 1)
    info.addField("Description:", json.motd.length >200? `${json.motd.clean.slice(0, 200)}...` : json.motd.clean);

  message.reply( { embeds:[info] } )
  
      }

module.exports.help = {
  name: 'mcserverinfo',
  aliases: []
}
```

is there anymethod to fix this or any other method instead of .json can we use something else

Comment: `fetch` returns a promise, so you'll need to use `await fetch(\`https://api.mcsrvstat.us/2/${Ip}\`)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetch` returns a promise, resolve the promise by using `await`

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const response = await fetch(`https://api.mcsrvstat.us/2/${Ip}`);
const json = await response.json();
```

Comment: thanks, it worked but it threw another error can you pls help I am editing the question

Comment: If I know definitely yes, share the error

Comment: Could you log field values like `json.port ` 
That error is thrown when there are no values in a message field

Comment: ok lemme try it

Comment: not able to console .log it the error is in line 21

Comment: ```.addField("port:", json.port || "Default", false)``` this is the line of code

Comment: What does logging `json.port` give you. 

If it is null/undefined do `json.port ?? "Default"`

Comment: ah it returns the port of the mc server in console

Comment: I did console.log(json.port) and added server ip as 2b2t.org and it returned 25565

Comment: do `.toString()`

Comment: I think that || "default" after json.port is giving error lemme try removing it

Comment: nope it dint work

Comment: Convert it to a string, `.toString()`

Comment: lemme try ok ig its like an integer so it throwing error coz it  shd be a string

Comment: Yes, as the error said non-**empty** strings